# how to formulate a timeshift CLI backup command to an external drive

Tags: command-line, backup

re: timeshift, using ubuntu 20.04 SERVER, (CLI), and an external drive (sdb1 a sandisk), how to formulate the command line so that the backup is directed to the external drive?

I successfully ran this line and it placed a backup on my root.
sudo timeshift --create --comments "first backup" --tags D

How to run a new backup so that it ends up on a mounted external drive?
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/sandisk

I can't find this info online.

I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

`man timeshift` is your friend. It includes the answer to your question.

`‐‐snapshot‐device <device> Specify backup device (default: config)`